# java for-loop in GUI TextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, for-loop, textarea

the question is really simple....I have a for loop to print a list of titles and append the results to the TextArea of GUI. for example the list contains titles A, B, C. Every time the TextArea should display the titles one by one. But, in my case, the print-out is always shows the whole list of titles. 
    My TextArea method is called inside the for loop. it should be appended the print-out for each loop but not entire list. how to solve it please help...

sorry for the confusing...I am using JTextArea to show the results. here is the code:

```
    private static JTextArea textArea1;
 ....
 ....
    textArea1 = new JTextArea(26, 38);
    textArea1.setLineWrap(true);
    textArea1.setEditable(false);
    sbrText = new JScrollPane(textArea1);
    sbrText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
....
....

public static void getStringText() {

    String ptime = passdata.getTime();
    String ppid = passdata.getPageid();
    String ptitle = passdata.getTitle();
    String previd = passdata.getrevid();
    String pparentid = passdata.getParentId();
    String puser = passdata.getUser();
    String pcomments = passdata.getComments();

    textArea1.append("Timestamp: " + ptime + "\n" + "Pageid: " + ppid
            + "\n" + "Title:" + ptitle + "\n" + "Revid:" + previd + "\n"
            + "Parentid:" + pparentid + "\n" + "User:" + puser + "\n"
            + "Comments:" + pcomments + "\n" + newline + newline);
    textArea1.setCaretPosition(textArea1.getDocument().getLength());
    // System.out.println(passToText.getPageid());
}
```

the getStringText() method is called inside a for loop.

here is the GUI i built. it shows the title with its information, cannot be print one by one means, in the for loop, it should be printed like A, and then B. the animation on the GUI should be shown A and then shown B. But in my case, it shows A,B, C at the same time...Sorry It hard to explain what I am seeing....

[image: here is the GUI I built]

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. What GUI are you using, which Text component? Can you post a bit of code or some screenshots? Are you saying that you want them to be on separate lines or you want to see some sort of animation?

Comment: one by one or whole list at a time, what difference does it make ?

Comment: Show the code for your attempt, and someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With out evidence to the contrie, it sounds like you're looping within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

This means that until you exit the loop (and the method), the contents of the `JTextArea` won't be updated to the screen

Swing is a single threaded environment.  The Event Dispatching Thread is responsible for, amongst other things, processing paint requests.  Anything that blocks this thread will prevent it from processing painting updates.

It is also required that all updates and interactions you make to the UI are done from within the context of the EDT...

You have a couple of options...

You could use a `javax.swing.Timer`, which will allow to trigger an `ActionEvent` on a regular bases, which is triggered within the context of the EDT.  This means that while the timer is "waiting", it won't block the EDT...

You could use a `SwingWorker`, which allows you perform processing in a background thread, but provides you with the ability `publish` results back to the EDT and `process` these updates within the EDT...

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

**Updated with example**

`javax.swing.Timer` acts as kind of loop (all be it an uncontrolled loop).  Every period, it will trigger.  You need to treat as if you have just looped another iteration and update the state of the UI as required...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TextTimer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TextTimer();
    }

    public TextTimer() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static final String[] TEXT = new String[]{
        "Why, you wanna tell me how to live my life?",
        "Who, are you to tell me if it's black or white?",
        "Mama, can you hear me? Try to understand.",
        "Is innocence the difference between a boy and a man?",
        "My daddy lived the lie, that's just the price that he paid",
        "Sacrificed his life, just slavin' away.",
        "",
        "Ohhh, if there's one thing I hang onto,",
        "That gets me through the night.",
        "I ain't gonna do what I don't want to,",
        "I'm gonna live my life.",
        "Shining like a diamond, rolling with the dice,",
        "Standing on the ledge, I show the wind how to fly.",
        "When the world gets in my face,",
        "I say, Have A Nice Day.",
        "Have A Nice Day",
        "",
        "Take a look around you; nothing's what it seems",
        "We're living in the broken home of hopes and dreams,",
        "Let me be the first to shake a helping hand.",
        "Anybody brave enough to take a stand,",
        "I've knocked on every door, on every dead end street,",
        "Looking for forgiveness,",
        "what's left to believe?",
        "",
        "Ohhh, if there's one thing I hang onto,",
        "That gets me through the night.",
        "I ain't gonna do what I don't want to,",
        "I'm gonna live my life.",
        "Shining like a diamond, rolling with the dice,",
        "Standing on the ledge, I show the wind how to fly.",
        "When the world gets in my face,",
        "I say, Have A Nice Day.",
        "Have A Nice Day.",
        "",
        "[Guitar Solo]",
        "",
        "Ohhh, if there's one thing I hang onto,",
        "That gets me through the night.",
        "I ain't gonna do what I don't want to,",
        "I'm gonna live my life.",
        "Shining like a diamond, rolling with the dice,",
        "Standing on the ledge, I show the wind how to fly.",
        "When the world gets in my face,",
        "I say, Have A Nice Day.",
        "Have A Nice Day.",
        "Have A Nice Day.",
        "Have A Nice Day.",
        "Have A Nice Day.",
        "",
        "When The world keeps trying, to drag me down,",
        "I gotta raise my hands, I'm gonna stand my ground.",
        "Well I say, Have A Nice Day.",
        "Have A Nice Day",
        "Have A Nice Day"
    };

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea ta;
        private int currentLine = 0;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            ta = new JTextArea(20, 40);
            add(new JScrollPane(ta));

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String text = TEXT[currentLine];
                    ta.append(text + "\n");
                    ta.setCaretPosition(ta.getText().length());
                    currentLine++;
                    if (currentLine >= TEXT.length) {
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.start();            
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried the timer but don't know how it works...it seems like  a delay of the actionPerformed...

Comment: That's right. The Indra would be that each to e the actionPerformed method was called, you would update your text area with new content, until you had completed. Once you have added all your content, you would stop the timer

Comment: Still confusing...for example I have:  

    timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
           for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
          textArea1.append(i + "\n");
            textArea1.setCaretPosition(textArea1.getDocument().getLength());
           }
           }
        });
...
...
    timer.start();    

It will append 0 to 9 together, not one by one...
how to solve this??

Comment: No.  On each tick, you need to update the text area with only the NEXT piece of data, until you run out of data.  The `Timer` is acting as a kind of loop