# JTextArea Append results from a for loop

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have the code:

```
   Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            textArea1.append("   "+i + "\n" + newline);
            textArea1.setCaretPosition(textArea1.getDocument().getLength());
             }
          }
       });
  ...
  ...
  timer.start();
```

It will append 0 to 9 together. I would like to print 0 to 9 one by one. That means, on the GUI JTextArea, it will show 0, and 1, then 2...with a bit of delay between each number. I have already ask the question but the question seems too confusing. So I wrote the simpler example above. Please help. Here is the original question of this issue if you guys are interested in:[java for-loop in GUI TextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332135/java-for-loop-in-gui-textarea)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do what you want:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
      private int i = 0;
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (i > 10) {
          timer.stop();
        } else {
          textArea1.append("   "+i + "\n" + newline);
          textArea1.setCaretPosition(textArea1.getDocument().getLength());
          i++;
         }
      }
   });
...
...
timer.start();
```

In the comments, it is mentioned that `timer` needs to be a field for this to work as shown. If you want it to be a variable local to a method, that method would look like this.

Notice that `timer` has to be final to be used in the anonymous inner class. But to make that work, you have to work around things by constructing the timer without any listeners, create the listener and then add it.

```
public void doit() {
    final Timer timer = new Timer(5000, null);

    ActionListener a = new ActionListener() {
        private int i = 0;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (i > 10) {
                timer.stop();
            } else {
                textArea1.append("   " + i + "\n");
                textArea1.setCaretPosition(textArea1.getDocument().getLength());
                i++;
            }
        }
    };
    timer.addActionListener(a);
    timer.start();
}
```

If you take the 1st bit of code and just put it in a method, you will get it complaining about not being final.

If you just make it final, it will complain that you can't call `stop()` on `timer` because `timer` might not be initialized.

Other solutions are mentioned in the comments. (Thank you for bringing this up, @kiheru)

Comment: Weird that the only answer which does not violate the Swing threading rules is located at the bottom without any upvotes. Changing that immediately !

Comment: Note to users: `timer` needs to be a field for this solution

Comment: @kiheru I think it can be final. I always let Eclipse complain and haven't bothered to memorize those rules.

Comment: @kiheru you can also use `((Timer)e.getSource()).stop()` and then there is no need to make it final nor make it a field

Comment: @LeeMeador It can't in this case, since it would be uninitialized when the action listener is created. A modified version, though, would work with a final local variable: creating the timer with a `null` listener, and adding it the real one with `addActionListener()`.

Comment: @kiheru Interesting. I tried it. If its final, it complains that 'timer' might not be initialized.

Answer (score -5):

What about using, `Thread.sleep(10)`

```
   Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

             for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            textArea1.append("   "+i + "\n" + newline);
            textArea1.setCaretPosition(textArea1.getDocument().getLength());
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                 }
          }
       });
  ...
  ...
  timer.start();
```

Comment: Ick! That blocks the EDT, and won't work either, since the blocked EDT does not have a chance to draw the changes.