# While Loops - Timed

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, sleep

I'm recreating a very poor version of cookie clicker just to test my skills a bit. Well I've come across a problem, I can't figure out how to repeat a loop every 3 seconds.
Main Class Code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CookieClickerGame {
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 200;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 200;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton cookie = new JButton("Cookie");
        JButton grandma = new JButton("Grandma");
        JButton robot = new JButton("Robot");
        panel.add(cookie);
        panel.add(grandma);
        panel.add(robot);
        frame.add(panel);

          /*----------------------------------------/
         /              Buttons                    /
        /----------------------------------------*/
        ActionListener listener = new CookieClicker();
        cookie.addActionListener(listener);

        ActionListener listener2 = new CookieClicker();
        grandma.addActionListener(listener2);

        ActionListener listener3 = new CookieClicker();
        robot.addActionListener(listener3);

          /*---------------------------------------------------------/
         /                       Frame                              /
        /---------------------------------------------------------*/
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Listener Code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CookieClicker implements ActionListener {
    static int cookies;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Cookie")) {
            cookies++;
            System.out.print('\f');
            System.out.println(cookies + " Cookies");
        } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Grandma") && cookies >= 10) {
            System.out.println("+1 Grandma | -10 Cookies");
            cookies = cookies - 10;
            System.out.println(cookies + " Cookies");
            while (true) {
                cookies = cookies + 1;
                System.out.print('\f');
                System.out.println(cookies + " Cookies");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
               }
        } else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Robot") && cookies >= 50) {
            System.out.println("+1 Robot | -50 Cookies");
            cookies = cookies - 50;
            System.out.println(cookies + " Cookies");
            cookies = cookies + 1;
            System.out.print('\f');
            System.out.println(cookies + " Cookies");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Not Enough Cookies", "You're Poor", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
           }
       }
    }
```

The `Thread.sleep(3000)` isn't working, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Define `isn't working`.

Comment: Take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332135/java-for-loop-in-gui-textarea/18332315#18332315)

Comment: surrond it with a try..catch to begin with

Comment: @John3136 I get this error "unreported exception java.lang.InterruptedException; must be caught or declared to be thrown"

Comment: @YassinHajaj Sorry, I'm VERY new at Java, I'm not sure what try..catch is

Comment: Thread.sleep() is susceptible to throw an exception that has to be caught somewhere... Google is your friend :)

Comment: I know, it is somehow boring, but very often it is easier to learn things "bottom up" instead of "top down". Meaning: you should first look into the essential basics of Java; before trying to solve the more advanced puzzles. So: "try/catch" is very basic; Swing applications, Threading and the rest ... is somehow way more advanced. In other words: it seems that you are willing to build a skyscraper; but you lack the skills to use a shovel to dig the hole for the basement ...

Answer (score 1):

Swing is a single threaded framework, you should never try and perform any long running or block actions from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

While you could use a `Thread` to solve the problem, a simpler solution would be to use a Swing `Timer`, as it's event callbacks are triggered within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, making it safe to update the UI from within

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Something like...

```
} else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Grandma") && cookies >= 10) {
    System.out.println("+1 Grandma | -10 Cookies");
    cookies = cookies - 10;
    System.out.println(cookies + " Cookies");
    if (timer == null || !timer.isRunning()) {
        timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cookies = cookies + 1;
                System.out.print('\f');
                System.out.println(cookies + " Cookies");
                // I don't know what your exit condition is, but you can use
                // ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                // to stop the timer from repeating
            }

        });
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

for example